# Yodlee Scheduled refresh vs instant refresh

Tags: yodlee

Does the **GetTransactions** API in new Yodlee API support instant refresh. The scheduled refresh seems to work fine but I am not able to conclude that instant refresh is not supported. All this assumes that the user is logged in and initiating a refresh scenario.

QuickBooks aggregation handled it automatically although they have a batch refresh algorithm similar to Yodlee.

Comment: Now that I figured out FastlLink can be used for both rerfresh and edit, it seems that Yodlee does not support a separate account refresh. Instead it supports the ProviderAccount refresh which basically refreshes all the accounts that have been added by the user on that particular provider. Also, another issue that I ran into was the Yodlee only supports instant refresh after a certain time has elapsed since the last refresh. Where do I find this value? It is certainly not any one of the refreshinfo values

Answer (score 0):

Scheduled refresh- Will be carried once in a day.

We do support Instant refresh- Please pass the providerAccountId to Update Account API (https://developer.yodlee.com/apidocs/index.php#!/providerAccounts/updateAccount) to trigger instant refresh for that Provider Account.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Makes sense. Please confirm the following and if possible answer my below concerns. Update ProviderAccount API triggers an site/account refresh and needs to be followed by the GetTransactions API to get the latest transaction, if any. However, how long does one need to wait after the UpdateAccount API to call getTransactions. Also, how does Yodlee handle MFA for scheduled and instant refresh.

Comment: Instant refresh ranges approx. 10- 90 secs to complete. Then after you see "Success" status, you must call GetAccounts API GetTransactions API to fetch the latest transaction. Please find the steps below

Answer (score 0):

**APIs-                 Description**

1   **Cobrand Login**-  Obtain the cobrand session.

2   **User Login/Register User**-   Obtain the user session.

3   **Get Providers**-  Search for Provider using the search string . For Ex: WellsFargo

4   **Get Provider Details**- Obtain the login form by passing the obtained providerId to this API

5 **Add Account**- Enter the user credentials in the login form and pass it to this API.

6 **Get Provider Account Details**- Pass the providerAccountId obtained from the "Add Account" API to "Get Provider Account Details" API, to get add account/refresh status and for any MFA form which is required by the bank.

7 **Update Account**-   Pass the MFA form (with valid value(s)) to "Update Account" under CredentialParams along with  providerAccountId.  (Can also be used to trigger instant user refresh)

8 **Get Provider Account Details**- Poll this API to get (add account)refresh status, consider different statuses present here.

9 **Get Accounts**- After successful account addition. Pass the providerAccountId to this API to get the account ids of that account and account level details.

10 **Get Account Details**- Pass the accountId to this API to get the account level details For Ex: Balance amount, Currency etc.

11 **Get Transactions**-    Use this API , to get the transaction level details (Pass the accountIds obtained and use the date filter) . Ensure to use the fromDate and toDate filter  else you will be receiving the last 30 days of transactions only.

Comment: We are using FastLink for adding user accounts.All MFA etc is taken care by FastLink itself. How can we invoke it for Account Refresh. Also, how does Yodlee handle Scheduled refresh where the user is typically not signed in. Who takes care of the MFA steps in that case.

Comment: Just re-posting my question. We are heavily relying on Fastlink to handle Adding user accounts to avoid the providing UX for site log in.  How does Fastlink help us in providing the instant refresh feature.